# Inheriting common functions in DurandalJS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, durandal

I'm looking for a better way to handle inheritance in my DurandalJS app, from `baseViewModel.js` to other pages. Here's my current app structure:

- baseViewModel.js
- main shell

  - group 1 shell

    - page 1
    - page 2
  - group 2 shell

    - page 1
    - page 2

All these pages share some common functionality (baseViewModel.js) such as:

- isLoading: an observable to check whether something is loading on the page
- isValid: checks if a form is valid
- afterAdd and beforeRemove effects for added and deleted items
- keyboard shortcuts for forms
- template switcher function
- etc

#### How it works at the moment

1. Everything inside `baseViewModel.js` is declared as `self.*` with self being a reference to the Window object, for example:

   ```
   self.showElement = function(elem) {
     if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).hide().fadeIn();
   }

   self.fadeRemove = function(elem) {
     if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).fadeOut(500, function() { $(elem).remove(); });
   }
   ```
2. I define `baseViewModel.js` only **once** inside the main shell and then access it across the app, like so:

   ```
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: dataArr, afterAdd: showElement, beforeRemove: fadeRemove }">
   ```

   or inside a view model:

   ```
   Page1.load = function() {
     self.isLoading(true);
     // get data
   };
   ```

#### What I tried

I looked into prototypal inheritance and managed to get it working, but I'm not sure about the way I implemented it. I created a `Base` function inside `baseViewModel.js` and returned it as a singleton. Then inside one of the pages, I did:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'jquery', 'knockout', 'baseViewModel'], function (app, $, ko, base) {

  var Page1 = function() {};

  Page1.prototype = base;

  return Page1;

});
```

The functions declared in Base work just fine in Page1's view and view model, but the problem is that I need them to work across all modules that have been loaded together with Page1. This includes:

- group 1 shell view (there's a button that activates a function inside Base)
- main shell view (the loading bar is visible based on the value of the `isLoading` observable inside Base)

To get these working, I had to define the file and apply the same `*.prototype = base;` in each view model.

So is there a better way to handle inheritance? And if not, is there a way to declare the base just once and have it apply to all subpages?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like prototyping is the way to go here.  Have you thought about registering base in require.js's configuration so that it can be used throughout with a common word such as baseVM.whatever()?  I don't know if it will get you what you are looking for so just throwing this in as a comment

Comment: Have you looked at typescript? It makes it easy for inheritance in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used prototyping inheritance in conjunction with a factory approach, and it seems to be working pretty well so far.  I only wanted simple inheritance, so this isn't a full-featured inheritance approach like some of the inheritance libraries.

As PW suggested, I do have my base view model wrapped in a requireJs module.

This is a simplified code example, but it should be functional.  Let me know if it doesn't make sense, and I can elaborate.

**Base View Model**

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    function ViewModelBase() {

        //this is the activate function that Durandal will call
        function activate() {

            //call activate on derived vm
            if (this.onActivate) {
                return this.onActivate.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //validate view model and display all remaining errors
        function validate() {
            // passing 'this' so that the viewmodel instance is evaluated at the time it's needed 
            return validation.validateViewModel(this);   //this is knockout validation
        }

        //exports
        this.activate = activate;
        this.validate = validate;
    };

    //return the constructor (non-singleton)
    return ViewModelBase;
});
```

**Factory**

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        createViewModel: function (ctor) {
            ctor.prototype = new (require("view-model-base"))();
            ctor.prototype.constructor = ctor;
            return ctor;
        }
    };

});
```

**Derived View Model**

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var factory = require("fusion/factory");
    var HomeViewModel = factory.createViewModel(function () {
        var __viewModel = this; //use __viewModel variable to access this view model instance.

        function onActivate() {
            //add application startup logic here

            //access public functions on the base view model like this:
            __viewModel.validate();

            return true;
        }
        this.onActivate = onActivate;
    });

    //returns the constructor (non-singleton)
    return HomeViewModel;

    //to return a singleton instead, do this
    return new HomeViewModel();


}); // END :: define statement
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I noticed that if I just use `Page1.prototype = new (require("view-model-base"))()` and `Page1.prototype.constructor = Page1` after I declare Page1 in the view model, I seem to get the same results. Are there any differences that I'm missing?

Comment: no, I think that's the same. I am developing a framework for an enterprise, and the factory gives me another layer of abstraction in case I need to change techniques or add functionality at a later point in time

Answer (score 0):

**mixins** is another pattern that might be considered for sharing functionality between modules.
**Please note** @Joseph Gabriel answer is definitively the correct one. Mixins are just a lighter alternative for some use cases, but they don't provide any kind of inheritance.

**Edit** Example and live version have been updated to better demonstrate where things needs to get placed in order to be a) common b) shared c) unique among all `Page` instances.

### common.js

```
/*globals define */
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function($, ko) {
    "use strict";

    // common must return a singleton
    return {
        commonObservable: ko.observable('commonObservable: Defined in common.js.  Click me...'),
        showElement: function( model, elem ) {
            var target = elem.currentTarget;
            if ( target.nodeType === 1 ) {
                $(target).hide().fadeIn();
            }
        },
        fadeRemove: function( model, elem ) {
            var target = elem.currentTarget;
            if ( target.nodeType === 1 ) {
                $(target).fadeOut(500, function() {
                    $(target).remove();
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

### page view model

```
/*globals define */
define(['durandal/app', 'jquery', 'knockout', './common'], function( app, $, ko, common ) {
    "use strict";
    var Page = function() {
        this.uniqueObservable = ko.observable('uniqueObservable: Page property. Click me... ');
    };

    // Extend the prototype with the common properties and
    // `extend` it further with shared properties
    $.extend(true, Page.prototype, common, {
         sharedObservable : ko.observable('sharedObservable: mixed in after common. Click me...')
    });


    return Page;

});
```

### page view

```
<div>
    <h1>mixin sample</h1>

    <ul class="unstyled ">
        <li data-bind="text: commonObservable, click: fadeRemove"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: sharedObservable, click: fadeRemove"></li>
        <li data-bind="text: uniqueObservable, click: fadeRemove"></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Live version available at: http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#extras/mixin